# How to create a \hline right before the last element of a table

Tags: tables, csvsimple

I am trying to add a line between my last and one line before the last element of the table with csvsimple-l3. To reiterate I want a line between 9 and 10 - is there some neat solution for this?

My csv file:

```
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.52,,0.07
```

My table in .tex:

```
\section{Tabuľka: }
\begin{center}
\csvreader[
tabular = cccc,
table head = & $\displaystyle\frac{a}{mm}$ & $\displaystyle\frac{\Delta a}{mm}$ & $\di
splaystyle\frac{|\Delta a|}{mm}$\vspace{5pt}\\\hline,
table foot = \hline
]{Tabulky/a-dimenzia.csv}{}
{\thecsvrow & \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii }
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Pic of the table:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once you know the number of rows, you can add a conditional `\hline`.

How do you do this automatically? You can read the csv file without typesetting anything and store the number of lines.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.52,,0.07
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{csvsimple-l3}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[
tabular = cccc,
table head = & $\displaystyle\frac{a}{mm}$ & $\displaystyle\frac{\Delta a}{mm}$ & 
$\displaystyle\frac{|\Delta a|}{mm}$\vspace{5pt}\\\hline,
table foot = \hline
]{\jobname.csv}{}
{\ifnum\thecsvrow=10 \hline\fi \thecsvrow & \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii }
%%
\qquad
%%
\csvreader[
  before reading = \sisetup{table-number-alignment=center},
  tabular = cccc,
  table head = \toprule & {$\dfrac{a}{\mathrm{mm}}$} & {$\dfrac{\Delta a}{\mathrm{mm}}$} &
    {$\dfrac{|\Delta a|}{\mathrm{mm}}$}\\\addlinespace\midrule,
    table foot = \bottomrule
]{\jobname.csv}{}
{%
  \ifnum\thecsvrow=10 \midrule\fi
  \thecsvrow &
  \tablenum[table-format=3.2]{\csvcoli} &
  \tablenum[table-format=-1.2]{\csvcolii} &
  \tablenum[table-format=1.2]{\csvcoliii} 
}

\end{document}
```

I present two realizations of the table, but I also recommend to remove the “mm” denominators and add in the table caption that “lengths are in millimeters”.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following solution makes the macro `\createtable` with two parameters: name of the `csv` file and the header of the table. This macro reads the `csv` file first by `\read` primitive, saves data to `\csvdata` and counts the lines. Then the `\csvdata` are read again by the `\prepcsvdata` macro which replaces end of lines by `\cr`, commas by `&` and inserts `\noalign{\cvsrule}` before the last line. Finally, the table is printed by `\halign` primitive.

```
\newread\csvin
\newcount\csvlines

\def\csvcount{%
   \ifeof\csvin \else
      \read\csvin to\csvline
      \if^\csvline^\else \global\advance\csvlines by1 \fi
      \global\expandafter\addto\expandafter\csvdata\expandafter{\csvline\^^M}%
      \expandafter \csvcount
   \fi
}
\def\prepcsvdata #1\^^M{%
   \advance\csvlines by-1
   \edef\replline{\the\numexpr\csvtotlines-\csvlines&}%
   \ifnum\csvlines=0 \def\replline{&}\fi
   \replcommas#1,\relax
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\csvdata\expandafter{\replline\cr}%
   \ifnum\csvlines=1 \addto\csvdata{\noalign{\csvrule}}\fi
   \ifnum\csvlines=0 \else \expandafter\prepcsvdata \fi
}
\def\replcommas #1,#2{\addto\replline{#1}%
   \ifx\relax#2 \else \addto\replline{&}\expandafter\replcommas\fi #2}
\def\csvrule{\kern1ex\hrule\kern1ex}
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\createtable#1#2{%
   \openin\csvin=#1
   \ifeof\csvin \errmessage{file "#1" not found}\fi
   \csvlines=0 \def\csvdata{}%
   {\endlinechar=-1 \csvcount}
   \closein\csvin
   \chardef\csvtotlines=\csvlines
   \edef\csvdata{\expandafter}\expandafter\prepcsvdata\csvdata
   % table itself:
   \vbox{\halign{&\kern.5em \hfil$\displaystyle{##}$\hfil\kern.5em \cr
      &#2\cr \noalign{\csvrule}
      \csvdata
   }}%
}

% test:
\createtable {dimenzia.csv}
             {a\over\rm mm & \Delta\over\rm mm & |\Delta a|\over\rm mm}
```

The macro uses only TeX primitives and basic plain TeX macros. You can use it in Plain TeX, in LaTeX or in whatever else.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

The rule before the last line of the array is drawn by Tikz after the construction of the array by using the PGF/Tikz nodes created under the cells, columns and rows by `nicematrix`.

```
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.csv}
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.5,,0.07
\end{filecontents*}
%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple} 
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\section{Tabuľka: }

$\begin{NiceArray}{ccSc}[cell-space-limits=2pt]
  & \displaystyle\frac{a}{mm}
  & \displaystyle\frac{\Delta a}{mm}
  & \displaystyle\frac{|\Delta a|}{mm} \\ \hline
  \csvreader[late after line = \\]
    {\jobname.csv}{}
    {\thecsvrow & \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
  \hline
\CodeAfter
  \tikz \draw (\arabic{iRow}-|1) -- (\arabic{iRow}-|last) ; 
\end{NiceArray}$

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations because of the PGF/Tikz nodes.

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

One way is to create table manually including both a header and a footer (the last row) with rules and let `csvreader` loop only over the data

[image]

```latex
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.4,-0.12,0.12
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
101.6,0.08,0.08
101.5,-0.02,0.02
\end{filecontents*}
%%%
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{csvsimple} 

\begin{document}
\section{Tabuľka: }

\begin{tabular}{cccc}
  & $\displaystyle\frac{a}{mm}$
  & $\displaystyle\frac{\Delta a}{mm}$
  & $\displaystyle\frac{|\Delta a|}{mm}$\vspace{5pt} \\ \hline
  \csvreader[late after line = \\,no head]
    {\jobname.csv}{}
    {\thecsvrow & \csvcoli & \csvcolii & \csvcoliii}
  \hline
  \stepcounter{csvrow}%
  \thecsvrow & 101.5 & & 0.07 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```